# USB hosting options

Tags: usb-host

I'm looking at a USB hosting application for the PIC platform, and it just seems that none of the compilers have good stacks available for USB hosting (though I've used CCS for usb devices with no problem) for those PICs that offer hosting.

Is there a good hosting stack available, or is the best route still the [FTDI Vinculum](http://www.ftdichip.com/Products/ICs/VNC1L.htm), or maybe even the [MAX3421](http://www.maximintegrated.com/datasheet/index.mvp/id/3639).  The MAX, in particular, seems like a fairly straightforward solution, but for some reason I haven't heard of many folks actually using it.  Can anyone report on actual experience with using that product for hosting?

Comment: I think you're going to find that most of the activity in embedded USB hosting is on ARM-based systems.

Comment: I haven't done hosting from a PIC yet, but I thought Microchip has a stack for that for their PIC32 parts.

Comment: For 8-bit microcontrollers, [LUFA](http://www.fourwalledcubicle.com/LUFA.php) can't be beat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microchip has USB Host examples as part of their application libraries (*Install Folder*\USB\Host - Mass Storage - Simple Demo\Firmware). I've used the USB Thumb Drive host in a number of projects. You will need a profile for every device type you are trying to host. What type of devices are you trying to host?